# Routing multiple WAN subnet on a single interface SonicWall NSA 2400

Tags: routing, nat, sonicwall, wide-area-network

In my current infrastructure I have the following setup :

```
ISP LINK 1 (64.30.24.128/26) ----|X3--sonicwall--X0|----LAN (64.30.24.128/26)
```

X0(LAN) is configured as

- Mode/IP Assignment: Transparent IP Mode, Splice L3 subnet)
- Transparent Range : Transparent X0 Range

X3(WAN) is configured as :

- IP Assignement : Static
- IP address : 64.30.24.130

64.30.24.129 being the gateway on the provider.

Now, I asked my provider to route a second subnet : 84.32.21.224/27

Their answer :

```
84.32.21.224/27 is currently routed statically over next hop 64.30.24.130
```

My question :

How do I add that second subnet to my current setup ? (without downtime if possible)

I'm not a routing/sonicwall expert, and quite frustrated that I cannot use all the IP's i'm paying for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add a static ARP entry for a single IP of the second WAN subnet provided by the ISP from Network menu in your sonicwall. You don't need any downtime for this. After adding ARP entry, do the required NATin and add firewall rule to allow the subnet.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but it took me a while to find a solution so I'm posting here for the sake of others.  I just faced a similar situation and I resolved it by adding a **Route Policy** following the instructions that I found on a [blog post](http://talesinit.blogspot.com/2013/08/sonicwall-nsa-when-your-upstream.html):

Using the addresses and ports from the question, here's what you should do:

1) Add an Address Object for the new WAN.

Under `Network > Address Objects > Address Objects`  click `Add...` and add the new WAN network provided by your ISP, with settings like the following:

```
Name...............: WAN-84.32.21.224/27
Zone Assignment....: WAN
Type...............: Range
Starting IP Address: 84.32.21.224
Ending IP Address..: 84.32.21.255
```

2) Add a Route Policy to route all the traffic to the new network to the WAN interface.

Under `Network > Routing > Route Policies` click `Add...`

```
Source.............: Any
Destination........: WAN-84.32.21.224/27   # name of the address object from step 1
Service............: Any
Gateway............: 0.0.0.0
Interface..........: X3                    # your WAN interface
Metric.............: 10
Comment............: Route 84.32.21.224/27 to X3
```

Now configure one-to-one NAT for the different addresses that you will use, e.g. `84.32.21.225 -> 192.168.0.225`

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  Thanks esp. for the link to the original blog post as well.